# Leaflet control layer: selector

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am displaying two Geojson files on leaflet. The two files are displaying fine on my map but I want to be able to have the selector working on both layers.

As you can see here, my selector only display on province : http://bl.ocks.org/renauld94/8493ca671ce8de63bfab9fafd3f3f574/363f40907203cc431de22e16987669b7bae13fe8

```
var ward = [];
var wardOverlay = L.d3SvgOverlay(function(sel, proj) {

  var upd = sel.selectAll('path').data(ward);
  upd.enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', proj.pathFromGeojson)
    .attr('stroke', 'red')
    .attr('fill-opacity', '0.2');
  upd.attr('stroke-width', 1 / proj.scale);
});


var province = [];
var provinceOverlay = L.d3SvgOverlay(function(sel, proj) {

  var upd = sel.selectAll('path').data(province);
  upd.enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', proj.pathFromGeojson)
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr('fill-opacity', '0.1');
  upd.attr('stroke-width', 1 / proj.scale);
}); 

L.control.layers({"Geo Tiles": tiles}, {"province": provinceOverlay}, {"ward": wardOverlay}).addTo(map);



d3.json("ward.geo.json", function(data) { ward = data.features; wardOverlay.addTo(map) });
d3.json("province.geo.json", function(data) { province = data.features; provinceOverlay.addTo(map) });  


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How I can have a selector for both layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the creation of [Control.Layers](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#control-layers-l-control-layers) :

> `L.control.layers(<Object> baselayers?, <Object> overlays?, <Control.Layers options> options?)`
>
> Creates an attribution control with the given layers. Base layers will be switched with radio buttons, while overlays will be switched with checkboxes. [...]

It means that the second object contains the entries for each switchable layer. Try:

```
L.control.layers({"Geo Tiles": tiles}, {
    "province": provinceOverlay, 
    "ward": wardOverlay
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer it works well! Im adding a 3rd layer now and have my third layer interacting with the first one which i dont want : L.control.layers({"Geo Tiles": tiles}, {"province": provinceOverlay, "ward": wardOverlay, "hospital": hospitalOverlay}).addTo(map);. How do i fix that? you can find my block here : http://blockbuilder.org/renauld94/cc0d2e321c5846ed0e508908e277335f